# Accessing UI from outside thread in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

In WPF, one could use something like:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Form1.grid.Items.Refresh()));
```

to access UI functions outside of the main thread. In Winforms however, the same functionality isn't there. What would be the easiest way to access a BindingList that exists inside of my Form1 class from my "working" thread? Currently I getting the following error when trying to access "Form1.record_list":

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

edit: I appreciate the help so far, but I'm lost on "this.Invoke". My method in the separate thread has no "Invoke".

Here's an example of my code so far.

```
        public static void listen(IPEndPoint server_ip)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In listen");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] received_bytes = udp_client.Receive(ref server_ip);
                string received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received_bytes);
                Record record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(received_data);
                Form1.record_list.Add(record); //This is where I assume the problem spawns
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }




public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static BindingList<Record> record_list = new BindingList<Record> { };
    public static DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread thread = new Thread(SCMClient.connect);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
        FillData();           
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[i].Value);
                if (row.Cells[i].Value as string == "OK")
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("IF WAS TRUE");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think the specific problem here is when I add Records to the Forms1.record_list. I'm not sure how to add items to that list without causing the Cross-thread error...

Comment: You are not using the `static` keyword appropriately.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You MUST access your UI from your UI Thread only. But you can use the [`Control.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) method - a `Form` IS a `Control` - to ensure your code is run from the UI Thread.

Also, you have a static `BindingList`, but I assume you want to display the contents of that list in an specific form. You should make the `BindingList` an instance member instead... or get a reference to a valid Form. The `Control.Invoke` method is not static.

There are several ways to do so. I would do it like so:

First, create a method in your Form class that adds the record to the list.

```
public void AddRecord(Record r) {
    if(this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.AddRecord(r)));
    } else {
        this.record_list.Add(r);
    }
}
```

Second, you need to have a reference to the form (in the next step, that is the `theForm` variable).

Then, in your listener method, invoke `AddRecord` method instead of adding the record in your `BindingList` directly.

```
public static void listen(IPEndPoint server_ip)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In listen");
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] received_bytes = udp_client.Receive(ref server_ip);
            string received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received_bytes);
            Record record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(received_data);
            theForm.AddRecord(record); // You need a Form instance.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, that was really well written and super helpful. Let me take a whack at this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider setting the answer as valid.

Comment: Ok, the only part I don't understand is why I can't just call `Form1.AddRecord(record);`  If I create an instance of Form1, wouldn't that just be a NEW instance of Form1?

Comment: In order to call `Form1.AddRecord(record)`, `AddRecord` should be a `static` method. Which could be, but then you would have to have a valid instance reference to call the `Invoke` method. Like so: `public static void AddRecord(Record r) { Form instance = /* Need this */; if(instance.InvokeRequired) { instance.Invoke(...); } else {...}}`

Comment: I mean... Somewhere you will have someting like:
`Form1 f = new Form1`
Just make sure that instance is available in your `listen` method, so you can just call `f.AddRecord(record)` in your `listen` method.

Comment: Eh, you lost me. I guess I don't understand static. I come from Python, so this is pretty unnatural to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123454/discussion-between-augusto-ruiz-and-mrdysprosium).

Answer (score 1):

The below will work out in winforms. Have tried once. The below code helps to update the label in UI thread from another thread.

```
string _string = "Call from another thread";
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
label1.Text = _string;
});
```

Comment: I don't understand "this" here. The function that I'm in (inside the separate thread) has no "Invoke"?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `SynchronizationContext.Current`, which works with both WinForms and WPF.

Note that you'll need to grab its value from the UI thread, since it's per-thread.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Grab the value of what?

Comment: I immediately get "The type name 'Current' does not exist in the type 'SynchronizationContext'...

Comment: Grab the value of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current, which does exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean. What would I do with that information?