# c# Multi threading operation triggered by a form

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Good day,

After being unsuccessful in my Google & Stackoverflow queries (not sure what I should search for), I'm posting here a public question.

I have a main form (frmMainMenu). Whenever this form is loaded and a button on this form is pressed, I'm trying to update a chart. However, as this could be CPU-demanding, I was considering calling the operation to retrieve the chart from another thread.

I'm constantly getting an error : *Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'labelX2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. System.Windows.Forms    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()*

The idea behind is also to display this symbol (referenced as the circularProgress1 control  [image] whenever data is being retrieved and to hide it whenever the operation is complete.

Here below is the code of my method in the userform :

```
[...]

private void feedDashboard()
{

Thread l_Thread;
ClsStartPgm l_Start = null;
try
{
  this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {
    l_Thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
      try
      {
        l_Start = new ClsStartPgm();
        l_Start.getDashboardInformations(
        this.labelX2, 
        this.circularProgress1, 
        this.tmr_Progress,
        this.chart1, 
        this.expandablePanel_1);
      }
    finally
    {
      // onCompleted();
    }
  });
  
  l_Thread.Start();
  }));
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
  ClsFinappErrorManager.manageException(exc);
}

finally
{
}
}
[...]
```

and if it can be helpful, here is my mentioned getDashboardInformations method of my Class ClsStartPgm

```
public sealed class ClsStartPgm
{

[...] 
// (Constructors, accessors and other methods not mentioned here 
// to simplify the reading of my question)
[...] 

    public void getDashboardInformations(
    LabelX pInformationText, 
    Controls.CircularProgress pCircularProgress, 
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer pTimer,
    Chart pChart1, 
    ExpandablePanel pExpandablePanel1)
    {
        List<double> l_DoubleList = null;
        List<string> l_StringList = null;

        try
        {
            pTimer.Start();
            
            this.m_Busy_Dashboard_Generation = true;

            this.m_Busy_Dashboard_Generation = false;
            
            double[] yValues = l_DoubleList.ToArray();
            string[] xValues = l_StringList.ToArray();

            pChart1.Series["MySerie"].Points.Clear();

            // Populate series data
            pChart1.Series["MySerie"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

            // Set Doughnut chart type
            pChart1.Series["MySerie"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
            
            // Set title of the expendable panel
            pExpandablePanel1.TitleText = "Situation: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

            [...]
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ClsFinappErrorManager.manageException(exc);
        }

        finally
        {
            l_Tuple = null;
            l_Accounts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please, could anyone guide me on what's wrong in my code? I'm definitely not asking to get the code written for me. However, I would be keen on understanding what I'm doing incorrectly here in my approach.

Many thanks for your appreciated help and best wishes,

Comment: See if this answer is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514556/9282880

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: Thank you Gec. So I was quite OK to use the "Invoke" method. But, how do I make the link between the start and the end of the event. In other words, how do I know when I can hide the circular progressbar?

Comment: The simple answer is that *UI objects can only be accessed by the UI thread*. And this has been explained in numerous answers. So there is no guarantee that it is possible to create the chart on a background thread. You could still *fetch* the data in the background, and do the UI updates on the UI thread.